# Alfresco: Get current form node

Tags: javascript, workflow, alfresco

I am writing a script to obtain properties from the current form (start of workflow), which has the type name *activiti$docWorkflow*. I have tried the following:

```html
var workflow = search.luceneSearch("activiti$docWorkflow");
logger.log("Start Script - selectpeople: " + workflow.properties["docWorkflow:selectpeople"]);
logger.log("Start Script - selectgroup: " + workflow.properties["docWorkflow:selectgroup"]);
```

However, *workflow* simply returns as undefined. How can I rework my search, or use a different method for obtaining the current form node so I can retrieve its properties?

Comment: Where / how is this code going to be run?

Comment: JavaScript task listener at the start of the workflow.

Comment: Why can't you just use the details passed into that script to get what you need then?

Comment: I've searched everywhere and haven't been able to locate how to achieve that. In the log I see that assoc_docWorkflow_selectpeople and assoc_docWorkflow_selectgroup get created, but I don't know what to do with that.

Comment: You should find the variables injected into your script. Just use the normal Alfresco script root objects to work with those, eg iterating over and fetching the details

Comment: Could you post an example or link to somewhere that has one? I'd love to give you some rep for helping me.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are trying to access all this workflow details just after initiation of new workflow.

There are two ways to handle that.

1) Inject Java task listner class during workflow start even. You just need to create that listner class and inject it in processdefinition following way.

```
 <process id="customReviewPooled" name="Custom Review Workflow" isExecutable="true">
<userTask id="reviewTask" name="Review" activiti:candidateGroups="GROUP_Reviewer" activiti:formKey="custom:activitiReviewTask">
  <extensionElements>
    <activiti:taskListener event="create" class="com.abc.cms.bpm.YouClass"></activiti:taskListener>  
    </activiti:taskListener>
  </extensionElements>    
</userTask>
<endEvent id="endevent1" name="End"></endEvent>
```

2) Inject Alfresco Javascript code

```
 <process id="customReviewPooled" name="Group Review And Approve" isExecutable="true">
<userTask id="reviewTask" name="Review" activiti:candidateGroups="GROUP_Reviewer" activiti:formKey="customwf:activitiReviewTask">
  <extensionElements>
    <activiti:taskListener event="create" class="org.alfresco.repo.workflow.activiti.tasklistener.ScriptTaskListener">
      <activiti:field name="script">
               <activiti:string>   

var outcome=task.getVariableLocal('custom_approveRejectOutcome');                       
                  logger.log("custom_approveRejectOutcome:"+outcome);
//Setting in local context
                  execution.setVariable('local_approveRejectOutcome', outcome);                     

            </activiti:string>
          </activiti:field>
    </activiti:taskListener>
  </extensionElements>    
</userTask>
<endEvent id="endevent1" name="End"></endEvent>
```

Comment: I have task listeners setup correctly. My issue is I can't seem to set the variables listed in my answer when setting them into execution variables.

Comment: In other words, the "//Your accessing logic goes here" is the part I can't figure out.

Comment: Hi Alan, I have added details.

Comment: Thanks, however I can't use "task" because there's no user tasks in this workflow. I can only use an execution script, and somehow need to obtain the form variables on workflow start. Hence the current node.

Comment: All properties which you take during begninning of workflow are workflow properties. For workflow properties you can directly access them using the property name with with it bind to. For instance "bpm_workflowDueDate" will give you due date property. So in your case I think you need to use logger.log("Start Script - selectpeople: " +docWorkflow_selectpeople);

Comment: So if I wanted to extract their username, would I use something like docWorkflow_selectpeople.properties.username?